# django model based forms - why isn't form valid?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to make model based form but something went wrong.

model:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/')
```

form:

```
class TopicCreationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = '__all__'
```

view:

```
def TopicCreateView(request):
    form = TopicCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TopicCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print('aaa') # It displays in console
    

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'blog/topic_form.html', context)
```

my form html part

```
<form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <fieldset >
       <legend> New Topic</legend>
       {{ form|crispy }}               
   </fieldset>
   <div>
       <input type="submit" value="submit" class="button-33" role="button">
   </div>
</form>
```

where did i make mistake ?

Comment: Share your `<form>` HTML part.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've just done it

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass both `request.POST` and [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES), so:

```
def topic_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TopicCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print('aaa') # It display in console
    else:
        form = TopicCreationForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'blog/topic_form.html', context)
```

In the HTML form, you need to specify that the files should be encoded with the [**`enctype="…"`** attribute <sup>[mdn]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    …
</form>
```